# MySQL UDF only returns integer - double wanted

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to create a UDF function in MySQL.

I'd like to return a 7 digit decimal/double based on the input arguments.

I installed the following function into MySQL like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION postrank_udf RETURNS REAL SONAME 'postrank.so'
```

The right result for my function Select postrank(120, 0, 1444763428) should be 13.8604775. However, it returns 14 now unless I do postrank(120, 0, 1444763428.0000000). Below is my UDF function. Any ideas?

```
   #ifdef STANDARD
   /* STANDARD is defined, don't use any mysql functions */
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #ifdef __WIN__
   typedef unsigned __int64 ulonglong;/* Microsofts 64 bit types */
   typedef __int64 longlong;
   #else
   typedef unsigned long long ulonglong;
   typedef long long longlong;
   #endif /*__WIN__*/
   #else
   #include <my_global.h>
   #include <my_sys.h>
   #if defined(MYSQL_SERVER)
   #include <m_string.h>/* To get strmov() */
   #else
   /* when compiled as standalone */
   #include <string.h>
   #define strmov(a,b) stpcpy(a,b)
   #define bzero(a,b) memset(a,0,b)
   #define memcpy_fixed(a,b,c) memcpy(a,b,c)
   #endif
   #endif
   #include <mysql.h>
   #include <ctype.h>

   #ifdef HAVE_DLOPEN

   #if !defined(HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R) || !defined(HAVE_SOLARIS_STYLE_GETHOST)
   static pthread_mutex_t LOCK_hostname;
   #endif

   #include <math.h>

   my_bool postrank_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
   void postrank_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)));
   double postrank(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args __attribute__((unused)),
                     char* is_null __attribute__((unused)), char* error __attribute__((unused)));

   my_bool postrank_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
   {
     if(!(args->arg_count == 3)) {
       strcpy(message, "Expected three arguments");
       return 1;
     }

     args->arg_type[0] = REAL_RESULT;
     args->arg_type[1] = REAL_RESULT;
     args->arg_type[2] = REAL_RESULT;

     return 0;
   }

   void postrank_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)))
   {

   }

   double postrank(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args __attribute__((unused)),
                     char* is_null __attribute__((unused)), char* error __attribute__((unused)))
   {
     double ups = *((double *)(args->args[0]));
     double downs = *((double *)(args->args[1]));
     double d = *((double *)(args->args[2]));

       double final = 0.00;
       double my_sign = 1.0;

       if(ups - downs > 0){
        my_sign = 1.0;
       }else if(ups - downs < 0){
        my_sign = -1.0;
       }else{
        my_sign = 0.0;
       }

       int myups = (int) ups;
       int mydowns = (int) downs;

       int my_max = 1;
       if(abs(myups-mydowns) > 1){
        my_max = abs(myups-mydowns);
       }

    double dbmy_max = (double) my_max;

    double result = log10(dbmy_max) * my_sign + ((d - 1444000000.0) / 64800.0);

    final = round( 10000000.0 * result ) / 10000000.0;

    return final;
   }

   #endif /* HAVE_DLOPEN */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, please try this little debug code and it prints what you expected.

```
#include <usual.h> 
int main(  )
{
  //  int ups = *((int *)(args->args[0]));
  //  int downs = *((int *)(args->args[1]));
  //  double d = *((double *)(args->args[2])); 
  int ups = 120;
  int downs = 0;
  double d = 1444763428;
  double debugd = 0.00; 
  double my_sign = 1.0; 
  if ( ups - downs > 0 )
  {
    my_sign = 1.0;
  }
  else if ( ups - downs < 0 )
  {
    my_sign = -1.0;
  }
  else
  {
    my_sign = 0.0;
  } 
  int my_max = 1;
  if ( abs( ups - downs ) > 1 )
  {
    my_max = abs( ups - downs );
  } 
  double dbmy_max = ( double ) my_max; 
  double result =
    log10( dbmy_max ) * my_sign + ( d - 1444000000.0 ) / 64800.0; 
  //  return round(10000000.0 * result) / 10000000.0;
  debugd = round( 10000000.0 * result ) / 10000000.0;
  printf( "\n debugd == %5.7f ", debugd ); 
}
```

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for the help. I tried this and it prints out 13.8604775  which is the right result. So I guess it's a MYSQL issue?

Comment: I doubt it. Probably, you are not reading or using correctly the float you are receiving. It is easy to overlook. Try to debug the part of your code that receives back the float. Add some printf step by step. If you are stuck then post more of your code.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the help. I've been debugging this for a long time. Can you help me take a look at this? the .c file seems normal. I just posted the whole file.

Comment: I cannot see any obvious bugs there but please get someone else to read it. I thought you were further processing before sending back to mysql, that's not the case. Asking the author of the tutorial seems your best bet.

Comment: thanks bob. I think I somehow figured it out. But it only returns integer now... in MySQL, not in C. C works fine.

Comment: Please, even it is MySql related, post a note explaining what the problem was, it will save someone else a few hours or days ! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Just did that.